# Fixing the height of my html to fit screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sleek looking calculator that will look decent on multiple screen sizes. I'm close to being done but I can't get ride of extra empty space below the calculator, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help. DX

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kevin's Calculator</title>
  
  <style>
   html {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0px; bottom:0px;}
   body {background-color:black; height:100%; width:100%; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px; bottom:0px;}
   .button {background-color: #cacacb; color:black; border:none; bottom:0px;
    text-align:center; text-decoration:none; float:left; font-weight:bold;
    display:block; font-size:32px; width:25%; height:14%; outline:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
   .mathPush {background-color: #0db2ff; margin:0px;}
   .button:hover {background-color:white;}
   .mathPush:hover {background-color:#80d6ff;}
   #keypad {display:block; width:100%; height:100%; margin:auto; bottom:0px;}
   #results {background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; font-size:32px;
   text-align:left; width:100%; margin:auto; height:20%;}
   #calculator {position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0vh;}
   #screen_1 {text-align:left; margin:auto; overflow-Y:hidden; overflow-X:hidden;
   text-overflow:hidden;}
   #zero {width:50%; text-align:left; text-indent:20%;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="calculator">
  <div id="results">
   <p id="screen_1"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="keypad">
   <button id="clear" class="button">C</button>
   <button id="inverse" class="button">+/-</button>
   <button id="precent" class="button">%</button>
   <button id="divide" class="button mathPush">/</button><br>
   <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
   <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
   <button id="seven" class="button">7</button>
   <button id="multiply" class="button mathPush">*</button><br>
   <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
   <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
   <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
   <button id="minus" class="button mathPush">-</button><br>
   <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
   <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
   <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
   <button id="plus" class="button mathPush">+</button><br>
   <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
   <button id="dot" class="button">.</button>
   <button id="equal" class="button mathPush">=</button>
   
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
 var firstArray = new Array;
 var secondArray = new Array;
 
 var next = false;
 
 var plusBoolean = false;
 var minusBoolean = false;
 var multiBoolean = false;
 var divideBoolean = false;
 
    var x = document.getElementById("screen_1");
    
    
  document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("1");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("1");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("2");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("2");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("3");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("3");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("4");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("4");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("5");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("5");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("6");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("6");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("7");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("7");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("8");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("8");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("9");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("9");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("0");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("0");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})

  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = true;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = true;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = true;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = true;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("equal").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (plusBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) + Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (minusBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) - Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (multiBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) * Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (divideBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) / Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
})
  document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function(){
  firstArray = [];
  secondArray = [];
  
  next = false;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: besides my answer I copied your code and made the changes myself so you can see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have 5 rows of buttons give each button a `height: 20%;` rather than a `height: 14%;` And since your results have a `height: 20%` give your keypad a `height: 80%` rather than a `height: 100%`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kevin's Calculator</title>
  
  <style>
   html {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0px; bottom:0px;}
   body {background-color:black; height:100%; width:100%; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px; bottom:0px;}
   .button {background-color: #cacacb; color:black; border:none; bottom:0px;
    text-align:center; text-decoration:none; float:left; font-weight:bold;
    display:block; font-size:32px; width:25%; height:20%; outline:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
   .mathPush {background-color: #0db2ff; margin:0px;}
   .button:hover {background-color:white;}
   .mathPush:hover {background-color:#80d6ff;}
   #keypad {display:block; width:100%; height:80%; margin:auto; bottom:0px;}
   #results {background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; font-size:32px;
   text-align:left; width:100%; margin:auto; height:20%;}
   #calculator {position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0vh;}
   #screen_1 {text-align:left; margin:auto; overflow-Y:hidden; overflow-X:hidden;
   text-overflow:hidden;}
   #zero {width:50%; text-align:left; text-indent:20%;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="calculator">
  <div id="results">
   <p id="screen_1"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="keypad">
   <button id="clear" class="button">C</button>
   <button id="inverse" class="button">+/-</button>
   <button id="precent" class="button">%</button>
   <button id="divide" class="button mathPush">/</button><br>
   <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
   <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
   <button id="seven" class="button">7</button>
   <button id="multiply" class="button mathPush">*</button><br>
   <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
   <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
   <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
   <button id="minus" class="button mathPush">-</button><br>
   <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
   <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
   <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
   <button id="plus" class="button mathPush">+</button><br>
   <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
   <button id="dot" class="button">.</button>
   <button id="equal" class="button mathPush">=</button>
   
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
 var firstArray = new Array;
 var secondArray = new Array;
 
 var next = false;
 
 var plusBoolean = false;
 var minusBoolean = false;
 var multiBoolean = false;
 var divideBoolean = false;
 
    var x = document.getElementById("screen_1");
    
    
  document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("1");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("1");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("2");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("2");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("3");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("3");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("4");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("4");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("5");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("5");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("6");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("6");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("7");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("7");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("8");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("8");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("9");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("9");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})
  document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (next == false) {
   firstArray.push("0");
   x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
  }
  else if (next == true) {
   secondArray.push("0");
   x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
  }
})

  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = true;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = true;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = true;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", function(){
  next = true;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = true;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  document.getElementById("equal").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (plusBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) + Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (minusBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) - Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (multiBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) * Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
  else if (divideBoolean == true) {
   firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) / Number(secondArray.join(""))];
   x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
   secondArray = [];
   console.log(firstArray[0]);
  }
})
  document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function(){
  firstArray = [];
  secondArray = [];
  
  next = false;
  plusBoolean = false;
  minusBoolean = false;
  multiBoolean = false;
  divideBoolean = false;
  x.innerHTML = "";
})
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```